# Using EntityFieldQuery to order nodes in an OG Group using node_comment_statistics table

Tags: organic-groups, 7, database

I have an EntityFieldQuery to fetch nodes of a certain type which belong to an OG group in a Drupal Commons instance.

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', array('post', 'document', 'link'), 'IN')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('og_group_ref', 'target_id', $panel_args[0], '=');
```

I was wondering if it was possible to also add the condition to order the nodes by most recent comment using the information from the `node_comments_statistics` table and the `last_comment_timestamp`.

Is this possible with EFQ since their are no joins? Or will I have to fall back to a basic Drupal Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the custom `TAG` to the EntityFieldQuery and than use the [hook_query_TAG_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) to add the JOIN to the query as below:

```
// Create the query as below (Note: "CUSTOMTAG" added for altering the query)
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', array('post', 'document', 'link'), 'IN')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('og_group_ref', 'target_id', $panel_args[0], '=');
  // Added the Tag, which we will be using to alter the query.
  ->addTag('CUSTOMTAG');
  // Complete the query (if you are having any other field condition).
  ->execute();
  
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_alter()
 */
function MyModule_query_CUSTOMTAG_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  // Add the join to the "node_comment_statistics" table.
  $query->join('node_comment_statistics', 'ncs', 'ncs.nid = node.nid');
  $query->orderBy('ncs.last_comment_timestamp')
}
```

Reference links:
https://drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-7634027
http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/or-queries-with-entityfieldquery/